# Fixing a poor measurement of drywall toggle anchors

Tags: hanging, drywall-anchor

I recently installed two metal drywall toggle anchors (similar to [this](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/fasteners/Anchors/Wallboard-Anchors/e-z-ancor-toggle-lock-self-drilling-drywall-anchor-100-25-pk?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CjwKEAjwotmoBRCc6LWd2ZnkuBYSJACyt2quJc89PKm51M3J2KRxhP6hDER19yjBLbSjAYkFyLcYxhoCKgLw_wcB). My measurements for these anchors turned out to be about 1/8th of an inch off, so they do not line up with the d-rings on the mirror I planned to hang. What methods can be used to fix this? If I can manage to get the toggle anchors out of the wall, can they be moved such a short distance with existing holes spackled and still hold? The anchors are rated at 100lbs and the mirror I am hanging is somewhere between 40-60lbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of the wall is gone in the direct vicinity, so moving the anchors you have will not work, and spackle is more a replacement for the paper on the drywall, than the gypsum itself.

Most useful, I think:

- Plan A: How to wire a picture, using 2 hooks. The hooks do not have to be level

https://www.flickr.com/photos/some_guy/16751622487/

Other Options:

- 1. mount a small piece of sturdy lumber, oak 1x2 molding (predrilled) would be fine  as parallel to the floor using the studs.

Drill for the screws to catch the d-ring on the mirror.

---

- 2. A low profile hook/bracket that you can screw into the anchor and 'swing' far enough to catch the d-ring on the mirror. A 45 degree angle on the hook will double the holding force on the anchor, so no more than that.

A loop of piece of picture hanging wire, quick link, modified simpson strong tie or the like is also valid here.

---

- 3.Get the anchors you have out of the wall

Cut (drywall saw, hacksaw blade, steak knife, ginsu or similar) the 1/8 over to where you need.

Get a couple of 'real' spring loaded toggle bolts, with the longest arms possible. You can get shorter screws if needed.

Build a washer 'sandwich' with the largest fender washer possible to go against the wall, as many normal size washers as needed to hook the d-ring, and then a larger washer against the toggle screw that will keep the d-ring from bumping/sliding off the front of the bolt.

With the exception of the washer closest to the screw head, they do not need to have the 'right' size hole in them, just enough to not fall through each other.

Expand, by cutting the hole in the wall just large to fit the toggle through.

Tighten as needed, and then get the mirror on the wall to prevent anyone from seeing the mess (I have this final activity down to a fine art.)

Answer (score 1):

You only get one shot on anchor placement, unless your going to move them both to new holes *at least* an inch away. At this point I'd be looking at modifying the D-rings: string some picture wire between them or make small loops on both.

Switching to toggle-bolts would give you an eighth inch of play, no problem. But you'd need a nut and a washer to stand it off, so it doesn't bottom out all the way against the wall.

Perfectly lining up anchors (and ending up level) with D-rings is exceedingly difficult; use wire. Luckily, you're *hanging* something and not trying to *attach*, for example, a towel bar.

[image] [image]

([framedestination.com](http://www.framedestination.com/metal_picture_frame_inst.html))